# How to run `task` or `onAppear` on NavigationSplitView detail for every selection change?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm trying to use `NavigationSplitView` with a `DetailView` that has a `task` or `onAppear` in it, but it seems it only runs once.

```
enum MenuItem: String, Hashable, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case menu1
    case menu2
    case menu3
    case menu4
    case menu5
    
    var id: String { rawValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: MenuItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(MenuItem.allCases, selection: $selection) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selection {
                DetailView(menuItem: selection)
            } else {
                Text("Default")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let menuItem: MenuItem
    @State var name = "Name"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(menuItem.id)
            Text(name)
        }
        .task {
            // This should be an async setup code
            // but for the sake of simplicity
            // I just made it like this
            name = menuItem.id
        }
    }
}
```

Initial application load
[image]

Initial menu selection
[image]

2nd to 5th menu selection
[image]

I know I can use `onChange(of: selection)` as a workaround, and then have my setup code there. But is there any other way to make `task` or `onAppear` work inside my `DetailView`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basing the View's `id` on the selection is not a good idea. It will force an entire `body` rebuild every time the selection changes, which will result in sluggish performance as the view hierarchy grows.

Instead, you can use the alternate form of [task(id:priority:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentedwindowcontent/task(id:priority:_:)?changes=latest_minor) to initiate the task when the `selection` value changes, like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: MenuItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
           …
        } detail: {
           …
        }
        .task(id: selection, priority: .userInitiated) { sel in
            print("selection changed:", sel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was searching for this quite some time. Solves my problem instantly !

Comment: great answer, thank you

Comment: This looks very good - can you make this a more complete example? It's hard to follow. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It is SwiftUI optimization, it recreates only dependent parts.

A possible solution is to make entire body dependent on menu item, so it will be recreated completely and calls task again, like

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let menuItem: MenuItem
    @State var name = "Name"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(menuItem.id)
            Text(name)
        }
        .task {
            // This should be an async setup code
            // but for the sake of simplicity
            // I just made it like this
            name = menuItem.id
        }
        .id(menuItem.id) // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Took a day of my life to finally get here and understand what Swift was doing behind the scenes.

Comment: This looks very good - can you make this a more complete example? It's hard to follow. Thank you